# Average time per capita for multiple columns & WHERE

Tags: sql

I have a table which looks something like this, with a few hundred more rows, detailing books of various genres and when they will be completed in the future (all of them have been started):

| book_type | genre | author | editor | translator | started_writing | expected_completion_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paperback | Romance | AG | Luis, Sarah | Hannah K | < timestamp> | < timestamp> |
| Paperback | Thriller | AS | Sarah | Joao K | < timestamp> | < timestamp> |
| Hardback | Comic | LK | Joao K | Suri M, Hannah B | < timestamp> | < timestamp> |
| Paperback | Romance | SM | Lola | Hannah B | < timestamp> | < timestamp> |
| Hardback | Crime | AG | Ian | Paola, Joao K, Hannah K | < timestamp> | < timestamp> |

I was tasked to calculate the genre output per capita (for each author, editor, translator), for three types of genres (Romance, Thriller, Comic; ignoring Crime) and I am at a loss. What I am asked to produce is something like this:

| genre | avg_time_to_completion_author | avg_time_to_completion_editor | avg_time_to_completion_translator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Romance | value1 | value2 | value 3 |
| Thriller | value 4 | value5 | value6 |
| Comic | value 7 | value8 | value9 |

The below is where I started from, but I don't know what to do next.

```sql
SELECT (SELECT genre
      FROM data_table),
      (SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(author, editor, translator))))
      FROM data_table) /
      (SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(started_writing, expected_completion_date, DAY)
      FROM data_table
      WHERE genre IN (Romance, Thriller, Comic))
      ORDER BY avg_time_to_completion_per_capita ASC
```

Can someone please help me understand what I need to do? This is a task I was asked to take over from a colleague, who's off sick for a few weeks and no one else has any knowledge. I don't want my colleague to work while they're in hospital but I have very basic SQL skills and am struggling.

Comment: The data does not include the date when it was fully written, edited, or translated. There's not enough information to compute the expected result.

Comment: Thank you! Can you compute the result if you expect every one of them did the same amount of work (ie effectively dividing through the SUM(author, editor, translator), ignoring how long each part took?

Answer (score 0):

A simple aggregation will compute the result you want. For example:

```
select
  genre,
  avg(expected_completion_date - started_writing) / 3 as avg_time_to_completion_author
from data_table
where genre in ('Comic', 'Romance', 'Thriller')
group by genre
```

**Note**: The date/time arithmetic depends on the specific database engine. The query should run in PostgreSQL, but you should change it if using a differrent database.